# What is the meaning of the <?php } ?> syntax in PHP?

Tags: php

Some PHP code, for example MediaWiki skins, contain the following line:

```
<?php } ?>
```

What is the purpose of that lone closing bracket?

Comment: It's almost certainly closing a control structure somewhere above it.

Comment: to ruin your site if it doesn't have a corresponding opening bracket

Comment: To close one opened bracket?

Comment: But that's the entirety of the code bit --- there's nothing above it that doesn't have a closing } ?>.

Comment: This file could be included somewhere with open bracket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All by itself without any other PHP code on the page, it is useless and will almost certainly cause an error.

In most cases however, you have a function or control structure somewhere on the page and this is just a closing brace.

**E.g.**

```
<?php 
      if (someCondition) {
?>
     <h1>Some title only shown if PHP condition is met.</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you - your example explained the structure to me!